Typing an RxJS pipeline
How do you define an OperatorPipeline<I, O> type (essentially the arguments you pass to Observable.pipe()) that takes zero or more RxJS operators and matches:

the pipeline input with the input of the first operator function
the output of each operator with the input of the subsequent one
the output of the last operator function with the pipeline output

This is the idea, but TS doesn't appear to like the way infer is used:
type OperatorPipeline<I, O> =
  | [ OperatorFunction<I, O> ]
  | [ OperatorFunction<I, infer T>, ...OperatorPipeline<T, O> ]
;

const createPipeline = <I, O>(target: Subscriber<O>, ...pipeline: OperatorPipeline<I, O>) => {
  doSomething();
};

EDIT: more variants as suggested by AI assistants, but none appears to work (TS still won't like the way infer is used)
type OperatorPipeline<I, O> =
  I extends O
    ? []
    : [OperatorFunction<I, infer X>, ...OperatorPipeline<X, O>]
;

type OperatorPipeline<I, O> =
  I extends O
    ? []
    : [OperatorFunction<I, infer X>, ...OperatorPipeline<X, O>] extends [infer _, ...infer Rest]
      ? [...Rest]
      : never;


To define an OperatorPipeline type in TypeScript that takes zero or more RxJS operators and ensures type safety throughout the pipeline, you can use variadic tuple types and conditional types
